# Use MediaTranscoder.PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync() with a memorystream?

Tags: c#, uwp, stream, transcoding

In the apirefference it says that the source cannot be a InMemoryRandomAccessStream or any other writeable stream. But i need to transcode a InMemoryRandomAccessStream. I tried converting the Stream but it didnt work:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream untranscodedVideo = GetStream();
Stream source = untranscodedVideo.AsStreamForRead();
await transcoder.PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync(source.AsRandomAccessStream(),destinatiom,profile);


InMemoryRandomAccessStream untranscodedVideo = GetStream();
IOutputStream source = untranscodedVideo.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
await transcoder.PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync(source,destinatin,profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i need to transcode a InMemoryRandomAccessStream. I tried converting the Stream but it didnt work.

The source parameter of [`PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.transcoding.mediatranscoder.preparestreamtranscodeasync) is `IRandomAccessStream`. For this request, you could use [`CloneStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.clonestream) method to converter `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` to `IRandomAccessStream`.

```
IRandomAccessStream irSteam = stream.CloneStream();
```